# Intellij shows every line in build.gradle.kts is red

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlintest

I created a new project from VCS (Kotlin and Gradle).  I added three `testImplementation()` calls to the `build.gradle.kts`.  IntelliJ didn't pickup the changes so I did `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart` and now Intellij shows every `implementation()` call and every `testImplementation()` call in red.  In fact every line in every build.gradle.kts in every module is red.

Intellij has lost its mind.  What do I have to do to restore IntelliJ's intelligence when it comes to kotlintest in Gradle?

Comment: Have you tried "Reload All Gradle Project"? Are there any error messages when you running `gradlew --tasks`?

Comment: Also gradle script support goes wild if there is some problem with applied gradle plugins...

Comment: What error is reported when you hover over the error in Editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I was finally able to solve this was with `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart`.  It must have been cache corruption.

Comment: didn't work for me, not even with clearing ~/.gradle/caches

Comment: same problem for me

Answer (score 6):

I started seeing this with AS 4.2.1. Invalidating caches and re-importing the project didn't work for me. I found [this article](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-17923) on the JetBrains issue tracker where people found that they had an extraneous JDK set in the project settings. While I did not have an extraneous JDK set in my project structure, I tried changing the JDK from the AS embedded version to an alternate AdoptOpenJDK 1.8 version I had installed. After switching to that version all the red went away and everything is resolving as expected. I was then able to switch the SDK back to the embedded version and everything continued working as expected. When switching back to the embedded version I did notice a brief message in the progress bar at the bottom of AS saying that it was processing a JDK 11. I'm not sure where that's coming from, but it does seem to be in line with what others in the JetBrains issue were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do to restore IntelliJ's intelligence when it comes to kotlintest in Gradle?

Re-import the project: File | New | Project from Existing Sources action and select build Gradle file to load the project from.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jdk.

Go to File>Project Structure > SDK Location > GradleSettings

Change the Gradle JDK to use the embedded or a compatible JDK (Azul JDK) if you're using a MAC.

Then Invalidate and refresh cache after deleting the .idea and .gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line to gradle.properties fixed the issue in my case

```
org.gradle.dependency.verification=lenient
```

Related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-21452

Answer (score 0):

I implemented all the above solutions, none of them worked. But when i moved the root folder location on my Mac using Finder to a different location, the red squiggly lines vanished.

Disclaimer: the red lines started appearing for me when I changed the project name and root folder name. So this fix may not work if the cause of your issues are different.